# How to avoid double numbers to use "e+" when there are very big

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display a `Double` in a label. When I have a `Double` this big `123 456 789 123 456.0` (I added the spaces to make it clearer) it's fine I get `123 456 789 123 456` on my label.

But when I add another number to my `Double` such as a `2`, instead of being `1 234 567 891 234 562.0` it is `1.23456789123456e+15` and then on my label, it's like if a `0` was added and not a `2` as I get `1 234 567 891 234 560`

Is there a way to not use the `e+` thing and keep the full Double?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can format the number using NSNumberFormatter. For example

```
import Foundation

var x = 123_456_789_123_456_000.0

var nf = NSNumberFormatter()
nf.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle

var s = nf.stringFromNumber(x)!

println(s) // 123,456,789,123,456,000
println(x) // 1.23456789123456e+17
```

Comment: Yes it works with a number such as an Int but when I use a Double it doesn't work anymore if the Double is too big as the Double value uses the e+ notation

Comment: I just tested my sample code with `var x = 123_456_789_123_456_000.0` and it works as expected. The formatter returns `123,456,789,123,456,000`. Without formatter it is `1.23456789123456e+17`. Did you try to run my code in Playground?

Comment: Yes I did. Now try with `123_456_789_123_456_001.0`, you still get `123,456,789,123,456,000` and not `123,456,789,123,456,001`

Comment: @Nico: that's because the 123,456,789,123,456,001 is not representable as a `Double`, so it gets *rounded* to the closest representable `Double`, which is 123,456,789,123,456,000.

Comment: @StephenCanon then is there a solution to my problem using something else?

Comment: Depending on how big numbers you need and if you need floating point or not, the numbers may fit into 64 bit integer. Or you could use Float80.